# How to tell if an SFTP upload was successful using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

Unfortunately the `getExitStatus()` method always returns -1 so i can't use that to tell me whether or not a file upload worked. I tried to use the `getInputStream()` method of the `Channel` class but whenever i tried to read from the inputstream my code blocked forever as if the `Channel` instance was still open/connected (even though the `isConnected` and `isClosed()` were false and true respectively - suggesting that the Channel was indeed closed). The following code always blocks after i try to read a byte of data from the input stream:

```
public class Put {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Session session = null; 
    Channel channel = null; 
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null; 
    InputStream in = null; 
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    try {
        jsch.setKnownHosts("known_hosts");
        session = jsch.getSession("user", "host", 22);
        session.setPassword("password");

        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        stdout = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        channelSftp.cd("/path/to/sftp");


        channelSftp.put("/path/to/localfile", "/path/to/remotefile");

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        System.out.println(e.id);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if(channelSftp != null && channelSftp.isConnected())channelSftp.exit();
        if(channel != null && channel.isConnected()) channel.disconnect();
        if(session != null && session.isConnected()) session.disconnect();
    }

    System.out.println("Channel is connected? " + channel.isConnected()); // returns false as i would expect
    System.out.println("Channel is closed? " + channel.isClosed()); // returns true as i would expect
    System.out.println(stdout.available()); // returns 0
    System.out.println(stdout.read()); // code blocks here

}

}
```

I suppose my questions are:

1. Why is my code blocking whenever i try to read from the input stream (even though the `Channel` is indeed closed)
2. What is the way to tell if a file upload worked or not. I guess if a SFTPException is thrown that's unsuccessful otherwise i can assume it was successful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I guess if a SFTPException is thrown that's unsuccessful otherwise i can assume it was successful?

That is correct. The various `ChannelSftp.put()` functions will throw an exception if they fail for any reason. If you want to double-check, you could call `ChannelSftp.stat()` or `...lstat()` on the remote filename afterwards to check it. But be aware that another process could hypothetically delete or move the remote file before you got a chance to check it.

You don't normally need to access the input or output streams of a `ChannelSftp`. `getExitStatus()` would tell you the exit status of the SFTP session as a whole, rather than the result of a particular operation.

JCraft has [an example program illustrating how to do SFTP](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) that you might find useful.

Comment: What if the file was already there and it didn't updated this time? "ChannelSftp.stat()" will still return proper status and we will not get to know if the upload was successful or not